# Php Connection issue(SQL STATE 2002) with MySQL while connection string is right

Tags: php, mysql, macos, symfony, connection-string

I couldn't push schema changes to MySQL DB from terminal.

I'm always getting 2002 error.

[image]

I have installed MySQL. It's up and running.

I'm using MAMP.

Here is my .env file

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=f492b5be321d353dbb48352876d4db75
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^(localhost|example\.com)$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# For a PostgreSQL database, use: "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://sampleUserName:SamplePassword@127.0.0.1:3306/prod_cat?serverVersion=5.7
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Here is my doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        mapping_types:
            enum: string       
#        unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
#        server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

To make it easy below I'm mentioning connecting string from  .env file

```
 DATABASE_URL=mysql://sampleUserName:SamplePassword@127.0.0.1:3306/prod_cat?serverVersion=5.7
```

FYI:

- Apache & MySQL is up and running.
- MySQL version number I have mentioned is right
- The user name and password is right.

Comment: is your mysql running and listening on port 3306? Ensure that `skip-networking` isn't in the mysql configuration? Connection refused is a purely network connection issue.

Comment: It's up and running. I don't know if it listens on port 3306 ? Ant ideas how to check that ?

Comment: I'm running the mysql using MAMP and I guess it's running on localhost. not sure how to check skip-networking ?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a sample PHP application with PDO. so that you can single out whether the problem is happening because of Some Symfony configuration or something to do with your MySQL configuration.

Comment: Is there on your directory another file beginning with .env?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H - I'll try a sample php application then

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant - No other file with such extension

Comment: Like @danblack said , it could be a port number issue. Check your port number by logging into **PhpMyAdmin**. You will see on top of the page **Server: localhost:{port number}**

Comment: Port number is the issue I guess. This is what my phpmyadmin says "Server: localhost:8889"

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H - I checked the phpmyadmin page , there is no option to edit port number ? any ideas

Comment: Go to **MAMP Preferences** and choose **Ports** tab there you have option to change the **port number** for MySQL & Apache or  else you can simply change your connection string with 8889 i.e  try use the following connection string  **DATABASE_URL=mysql://sampleUserName:SamplePassword@127.0.0.1:8889/prod_cat?serverVersion=5.7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue where there is a **mismatch in port number of MySQL** and What's in **Connection String**.

Find port number of MySQL by visiting MySQL page in **PhpMyAdmin** and use the port number in your Connection String or else use the port number of connection string in MySQL port setting.

To change the MySQL Port. Go to Preferences in MAMP and Choose Ports tab and you can update it there.

[image]